# Get value from object with specific attribute values

Tags: php

I get a output which is a collection of user memberships. I need to filter my output so that i get 'mon_id' where u_id equals req_uid aka 13 and at the same time g_id equals req_grp aka 4.

```
 $req_uid=13;
$req_grp=4;

$output={"main_id":"dcb912dcb912"}{
"7":[{"mon_id":14,"g_id":1,"u_id":7}],
"1":[{"mon_id":1,"g_id":1,"u_id":1}, {"mon_id":2,"g_id":2,"u_id":1}],
"4":[{"mon_id":7,"g_id":1,"u_id":4},{"mon_id":32,"g_id":2,"u_id":4}],
"13":[{"mon_id":28,"g_id":1,"u_id":13},{"mon_id":29,"g_id":4,"u_id":13}],
"6":[{"mon_id":13,"g_id":1,"u_id":6}],"12":[{"mon_id":22,"g_id":1,"u_id":12}],
"2":[{"mon_id":3,"g_id":1,"u_id":2},{"mon_id":31,"g_id":2,"u_id":2},{"mon_id":33,"g_id":4,"u_id":2}],
"9":[{"mon_id":16,"g_id":1,"u_id":9}],
"5":[{"mon_id":11,"g_id":1,"u_id":5},{"mon_id":12,"g_id":2,"u_id":5}],
"10":[{"mon_id":18,"g_id":1,"u_id":10}],
"8":[{"mon_id":15,"g_id":1,"u_id":8}]
}


$myjson = json_decode($output, true);
foreach($myjson as $key => $value){
    //filter...
}
```

Comment: your JSON is not valid... `{"main_id":"dcb912dcb912"}{` needs to be `{"main_id":"dcb912dcb912",` and close the $output assignment off with a `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top-level JSON output is an object that maps user IDs to subscription lists. So you can iterate over the subscription lists and take the ones that match your search criteria:

```
$reqUid = 13;
$reqGrp = 4;
$monIds = array();

foreach ($userSubscriptions as $userId => $subscriptions) {
    foreach ($subscriptions as $subscription) {
        if ($subscription['u_id'] == $reqUid && $subscription['g_id'] == $reqGrp) {
            $monIds[] = $subscription['mon_id'];
        }
    }
}

print('Found ' + count($monIds) + ' matching mon_id values');
```